# Project with path ':expo-modules-core' could not be found in project ':expo'

Tags: build, expo, eas

I am facing this problem when trying to deploy my expo app with the eas build -p android --profile preview, but I am getting the error

Project with path ':expo-modules-core' could not be found in project ':expo'

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks a lot :)